# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list en javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, onclick, sintaxis

tengo un error a la hora de hacer click en un div,me da el siguiente error
Es una pagina que al presionar un div debe decir presionado mas el nombre de la pelicula

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

les adjunto el código

```
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

var db = firebase.firestore();

function Presionar(id) {
    console.log("Presionado "+id)
}

db.collection("Peliculas").onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
    document.getElementById('Contenedor').innerHTML = "";


    querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        var idpelicula = doc.id;
        var nombre = doc.data().Nombre_Pelicula;
        var genero = doc.data().Genero;
        var marca = doc.data().Marca;
        var vista = doc.data().Vista;
        var tipo = doc.data().Tipo;
        var endisco = doc.data().En_Disco;
        var poster = doc.data().Poster;

        document.getElementById('Contenedor').innerHTML +=

            `   
<div onclick="Presionar(${nombre})" style="width:100px;height:200px;border:2px blue dashed;float:right">
<img width="100px" height="200px" src="${poster}">
</div>
})
})
```

Comment: Hola cuando haces document.getElementById('Contenedor').innerHTML += debe de estar entre comillas  asi document.getElementById('Contenedor').innerHTML += '<div></div>'

Answer (score 0):

El contenido del `div` no es reconocido como una cadena, por tanto estás teniendo el error.

En casos como esto puedes usar las comillas invertidas para agrupar una cadena con comillas y nombres de variables incluidas entre `${}`.

También, te recomiendo crear una sola referencia a los elementos del DOM, así evitas llamadas constantes a `document.getElementById` que es más costoso.

Por ejemplo:

```js
//Dos variables sólo para prueba
var nombre="Lorem ipsum";
var poster="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/4.sm.jpg";
//Referencia al elemento
var elContenendor=document.getElementById('Contenedor');
//Trabajamos con variables para más claridad: NÓTESE que la cadena abre y cierra con `
var divData=`<div onclick="Presionar(${nombre})" style="width:100px;height:200px;border:2px blue dashed;float:right">
<img width="100px" height="200px" src="${poster}">
</div>`;
//Usamos la referencia antes creada
elContenendor.innerHTML += divData;
```

```html
<div id="Contenedor"></div>
```

## Una recomendación

Recomendaría también que evites poner funciones *in line*  en los elementos HTML, como por ejemplo el `onclick`. Haciendo eso no hay independencia entre el código HTML y el código Javascript, lo cual dificulta el mantenimiento y el análisis del código. Si en un programa grande invocas esa función *in line*  y un día dicha función tiene que evolucionar, tendrás que empezar a buscar todos los archivos con el HTML que la implementa (si son cientos o miles de archivos imagina el dolor de cabeza). Por eso es mejor asignar los `onclick` mediante listeners, en el código Javascript, liberando de ese modo el `div` de llamadas *in line*.